# Bash script for automating cntlm proxy password generation

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, interactive

I want to use the tool cntlm to authenticate via basic authentication against our corporate proxy server, which uses the ntlm protocol.

CNTLM uses a cntlm.conf file to get your proxy authentication credentials.
If you don't want to use your password in plain text, you can generate hashes with the command. (That's what I want!)

`cntlm -u <user> -d <domain> -f -H`.

The problem here is, that we use a rolling password policy here and I want to write a bash script for automating the hash generation, inserting in the config file and restarting the cntlm service.

Unfortunately the above shown command generates the password hashes interactively and I couldn't find a way to wrap this in a bash script.

I am a bash scripting newbie though and could use some advice here ;)

Comment: Do you know exactly what the shell script is supposed to pass to `cntlm`? I mean does it depend on the user, or you can retrieve these values automatically.

Comment: I have to insert the password, so it depends on the user... But I thought I could wrap it and pass it to cntlm as a parameter, but this does not work, or I don't know how

Comment: Of course you can wrap it. Passing input to an interactive program is not a problem either. I just don't quite understand the problem.

Comment: The problem is the following: If I get a interactive input from the user, how do i pass this to the cntlm command interactively? cntlm needs to get the password information interactively to generate the hashes. If I just ran cntlm and pipe it like so `cntlm -u <user> -d <domain> -f -H > hashes` it does not wait for interactive input.

Comment: Oh, this is not true...

Comment: I see, I have to learn bash. There is no way around this...

Comment: I still don't understand. To pass something to to an interactive program you can use here documents http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Answer (score 1):

For my cntlm version (0.92.3) a simple echo pipe works like charm:

echo "PASSWORD" | cntlm -u USER -d DOMAIN -f -H

Comment: On Windows (especially cmd.exe) do skip quotes and spacebefore pipe making it
`echo PASSWORD| cntlm -u USER -d DOMAIN -f -H`